# Run LAN game through VPN

Tags: games, vpn, openvpn, lan

I want to play an old ass game that only works through LAN with a friend online. Is it possible to do this through a VPN and if it is, can someone give me instructions on how to do so. Please make them simple, I have no technical knowledge of how VPNs work. Thank you.

*I already have openVPN installed

Comment: I don't understand this "through **LAN** with a friend **online** " ?

Comment: @SeverusTux LAN basically means having the same subnet... being on the same network.  Through VPN (Virtual Private Network) people can be on the same network in different locations.

Comment: "I have no technical knowledge of how VPNs work. "  This is going to be a problem.  This because you will need to set up an OpenVPN server, and have both players connect to that server.  OpenVPN typically uses routing, so only when both player are connected, you'd be on the same subnet.  Furthermore you'll have to configure OpenVPN to allow two clients to talk to each other.
To set up an OpenVPN server, you'll either have to rent a VM somewhere or host one yourself and port forward 1194/udp from your router to that server.  This is a non-trivial task and goes way beyond a "Ask Ubuntu", IMHO.

Comment: Since you mentioned you already have openVPN installed, I inferred you have it configured.  I provided the steps for connecting to your openVPN server in a answer.  If you have problems with the steps, `pptp` is simpler and can easily be done from a script run by both client and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that both you and the other person logs into the same VPN.  You give them your VPN IP address and they give you theirs.

If you have VPN setup as a server, then you would have to log into your VPN Server as a client.  The other person would do the same.

You can log into your VPN network a number of ways.  The GUI way is with `NetworkManager`.

First install or ensure openvpn support is provided for NetworkManager.  You can do this by installing the network-type support.

```
$ sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Now click the `Network ICON` in the Status bar; point to VPN, then click `Configure VPN`.

From this GUI Click `Add` and choose the `OpenVPN` type.  Fill out the credentials from your VPN server, then connect to it the same way you connect to a wireless connection.

Have your friend to the same thing.

You can check the VPN IP address with this cli:

```
$ hostname -I
```

OpenVPN's default port is UDP port 1194.  You would have to configure your router to forward port to your computer's IP address.  You can get the IP address via the `hostname -I` command and.

Comment: is it possible to host the server on my pc itself?

Comment: @yolo7398 Yes.  The answer is from that perspective... the host is you.

Comment: ok, I get it. How will I configure my router to forward port to my computer's IP address?

Comment: It would depend on the router.  They will all have a section called `Port Forwarding`.  Brought thought the router's web interface  (ie. http://192.168.0.1) for `Port Forwarding`.   It'll most likely be in the `security section`.  There you would specify your computer's IP, the protocol is UDP and of course the Port to forward is 1194.